# HTTP 500 Internal server error, in android release build

Tags: android, http, retrofit2, http-status-code-500

I have a retrofit call to my server that returns JSON data. I have been working on the debug build since the first day and everything looked fine. Just yesterday I generated a release build (android) and found the call is failing with exception as "HTTP 500, internal server error".

I am unable to understand what is the difference between the two that I fall into such a state.
Code to make the retrofit is as under,

```
public void populateFeeds(final String market, final String category, final String msaToken, final String language, final List<CategorizedFeeds> categorizedFeedsList){
        VmFeedsHub.this.feedClusterDataSetUpdate.set(false);
        VmFeedsHub.this.feedCategoryDataSetUpdate.set(false);
        BackendFactory.getFeedsServiceBackend().getFeedsMetadata(market, category, null, null)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<Feeds>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        ALog.i(TAG, LOG_PREFIX + " Feeds data retrieved empty/null for market: " + market + " with exception: " + e.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Feeds feeds) {
                        ALog.i(TAG, LOG_PREFIX + " Feeds data retrieved successfully with feed count: " + feeds.getFeedsMetaDataArrayList().size() + " for market: " + market);
                        for (CategorizedFeeds categorizedFeeds : feeds.getFeedsMetaDataArrayList()) {
                            List<FeedMetadata> feedMetadataList = new ArrayList<>();
                            for(FeedsMetadata feedsMetadata : categorizedFeeds.getFeedsMetadataArrayList()){
                                FeedMetadata feedMetadata = new FeedMetadata(feedsMetadata.getHeadlineText(), feedsMetadata.getHeadlineImageURL(), feedsMetadata.getProviderName(), feedsMetadata.getProviderImageURL(), feedsMetadata.getPublishedDateTime(), feedsMetadata.getFeedURL(), feedsMetadata.getCmsId());
                                feedMetadataList.add(feedMetadata);
                            }
                            CategorizedFeeds categorizedFeed = new CategorizedFeeds(categorizedFeeds.getCategory(), feedMetadataList);
                            categorizedFeedsList.add(categorizedFeed);
                        }
                        if(category.equals(CATEGORY_CLUSTER))
                            VmFeedsHub.this.feedClusterDataSetUpdate.set(true);
                        else
                            VmFeedsHub.this.feedCategoryDataSetUpdate.set(true);
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: Is your release build running Proguard ?

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure what to disable/enable to make sure this works @pdegand59

Answer (score 2):

My solution for this issue is to keep the model classes for retrofit.

Add this code in your **proguard-rules.pro** file

```
# keep model classes for retrofit
# packagename.directory.** { *; } 

-keep class com.packagename.mac.model.** { *; }
-keep class com.packagename.mac.data.response.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem here was with the POST body that I was sending. In the custom Object the proguard was renaming the variables and hence server was unable to intercept them. Added @SerializedName annotation fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
-keep class com.packagename.path_name_to_models
```

give the path to the model classes you are using, the issue will be solved